# next-auth google signin issue (OAuthAccountNotLinked) caus of MongoDBAdapterOptions.collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I am currently facing an issue with NextAuth's Google sign-in when using the MongoDBAdapter.

- The problem arises when I customize the collection name in the MongoDBAdapterOptions.
- Specifically, when I set the collections.Users to "deltas," the
  sign-in process does not work as expected, resulting in an
  OAuthAccountNotLinked error and improper redirection with the session
  to the homepage.

temp fix:
Issue Resolution:

Removing the custom collection name (Users: "deltas") resolves the problem, but it creates an additional "User" collection which I want to avoid.

Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered similar issues with NextAuth Google sign-in and MongoDBAdapter custom collection names?
2. How can I configure the MongoDBAdapter to use my "Deltas" collection without causing sign-in issues?
3. Is there a specific configuration or workaround to ensure proper redirection with the session to the homepage after Google sign-in?

connectMongoDb.ts

```
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";

const { MONGODB_URI } = process.env;

// connection function
export const connect = async () => {
  console.log("triggered---", MONGODB_URI);
  if (!MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please define the DATABASE_URL environment variable inside .env.local"
    );
  }

  const conn = await mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URI as string)
    .catch((err) => console.log("mongoose error from connectMongoDb:",err));

  const DeltaSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      cname: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  // OUR Delta MODEL
  const Delta = mongoose.models.Delta || mongoose.model("Delta", DeltaSchema);

  return { conn, Delta };
};
```

mongodb.ts

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

const uri: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
let client: MongoClient;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {

  let globalWithMongoClientPromise = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
  };

  if (!globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri);
    globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

authOption

```js
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
    collections: {
      Users: "deltas",
    },
  }),
  callbacks:{
   async signIn({user, account}){
       if (account?.provider === "google") {
        const { name, email } = user;
        try {
          console.log("Before fetch to API login");
          const { Delta } = await connect();
          // Check if the user already exists in the database
          let user = await Delta.findOne({ email });
          // If the user doesn't exist, create a new user with initial credits
          if (!user) {
            await Delta.create({
              name:customName(),
              email,
            });
          }

          return true;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error during API login:", error);
          // If there is an error, throw it to stop the sign-in flow
          throw new Error("Error during API login");
        }
      }
      return false;
   }
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      const { picture, aToken, exp, ...jwtPayloadWithoutPic } = token;

      const customExpiration = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // 3600 seconds = 1 hour

      const newToken = jwt.sign(
        { ...jwtPayloadWithoutPic },
        JWT_SECRET as string,
        {
          expiresIn: customExpiration,
        }
      );
      if (account) {
        token.aToken = newToken;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        cusToken: token?.aToken,
      };
    },
    
  pages:{
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify",
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
```

url => `localhost:3000/auth/login`

button => `sigin(google)`

choosing an account

url changes => `localhost:3000/auth/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&error=OAuthAccountNotLinked`